# Make Spring Security recheck Authorities/Roles for each request

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

***Summary:***

I want my oauth client to re fetch the Authorities from the oauth authorisation server for every request, so any changes to the users Authorities are reflected straight away.

***Details:***

I have a Spring Boot web app that is secured with **@EnableOauth2Sso**.

I have written my own oauth authorisation app, that is secured using **@EnableAuthorizationServer**.

My web app is set to use the authorisation code grant type.  This all works fine, and I can log in to my web app against the authorisation app, with whole oauth2 dance occurring correctly resulting in the authorisation code being swapped for an access token.

Once we have the access token back in the web app, as part of the initial authentication, spring security on the web app is then calling the /oath/check_token end point on the authorisation server and storing the returned user info in the HTTP session.

How can I stop this, and make it re request the user info from the authorisation server for every request to the web app?

Comment: In my Applicaiton this is the default behavior. Did you try to set a debug point at the user controller to check whether userinfo is reqeuested for each request? In my case this happens